# Query to delete record when no matching in delta table

Tags: sql, db2, sql-delete, ibm-midrange

please help to write a better delete query. DB2 does not have "not matched by source" with merge.
Need to delete rows which does not have matching codes from source file for an ID and need to delete rows only for the ID's present in source file.

```
delete from target
   where ID in ( select ID from source)
         and 
      ID concat Code NOT in ( Select S.ID concat S.Code from source S)
```

sample data

```
target             source 
ID   code         ID   code         
1    ABC          1     ABC     
1    DEF          1     DEF
1    IJK
2    ABC
2    XYZ
```

row with value ID=1 & code=IJK alone need to be deleted from target

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. Doesn't look to difficult to do, but without an example is difficult to tell.

Comment: added sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
delete from target
where (id, code) in (
  select t.id, t.code
  from target t
  left join source s on (s.id, s.code) = (t.id, t.code)
  where s.id is null and t.id in (select id from source)
);
```

Result:

```
 ID  CODE 
 --- ---- 
 1   ABC  
 1   DEF  
 2   ABC  
 2   XYZ
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=f53ce50be9858b4f9216f4a76d0f1d12).

I'm sure the syntax can be compressed using `DELETE` & `JOIN` or using `EXISTS` instead of `IN`, but this example should be a good solution.